# How to get authenticated person from Google Doorbell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to send a message from Google Doorbell to GCP pub/sub and I want to get an authenticated person name(or ID).

I can get a Person Event but this does not contain an authenticated person name. Is there a way to get the name of an authenticated person?

Thanks

Comment: Show what you are getting. I know Pub/Sub and Google Cloud very well, but I do not know anything about Google Doorbell.

Comment: Could you please clarify what "Google Doorbell" refers to? Where is the Person event defined?